# SQL Server stored procedures for INSERT and UPDATE, better to separate or condense?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating stored procedures for inserting and updating data in my SQL Server database. At first I was creating a separate procedure for Add/Set but then I stumbled across a query that allows me to condense them into a single procedure. I wanted to check with the SO community on any possible future issues doing it this way.

**Separate Procedures**

```
--INSERT Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDataType]
    @TypeName [nvarchar](255),
    @TypeProperty [nvarchar](255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO DataType(TypeName, TypeProperty)
    VALUES(@TypeName, @TypeProperty)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

--UPDATE Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetDataType]
    @ID [int],
    @TypeName [nvarchar](255),
    @TypeProperty [nvarchar](255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE DataType SET TypeName = @TypeName, TypeProperty = @TypeProperty
    WHERE ID = @ID
 END

EXEC AddDataType @TypeName = 'Test Name', @TypeProperty = 'Test Property' --INSERT
EXEC SetDataType @ID = 42, @TypeName = 'Test Name', @TestProperty = 'Test Property' --UPDATE
```

**Combined**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetDataType]
    @ID [int] = NULL,
    @TypeName [nvarchar](255),
    @TypeProperty [nvarchar](255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE DataType SET TypeName = @TypeName, TypeProperty = @TypeProperty
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO DataType(TypeName, TypeProperty)
        VALUES(@TypeName, @TypeProperty)

    IF @ID IS NULL
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

EXEC SetDataType @TypeName = 'New Type Name', @TypeProperty = 'New Type Property' --INSERT
EXEC SetDataType @ID = 42, @TypeName = 'Updated Type Name', @TypeProperty = 'Updated Type Property' --UPDATE
```

So far I have 15 type tables that I creating procedures for and am trying to cut down on the number of procedures created, however I don't want to sacrifice performance. I know the second method is more processing, but would it be significant enough to cause issues? I don't see the type tables holding mass amounts of data, no more than 100 records with the average being around 10-20.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I personally prefer having separate, focused procedures - I don't like those "do-it-all-and-then-some-more" methods that do all sorts of things - all depending on what values you pass in....

Comment: @marc_s I'm okay with those for search procedures, where much of the logic is unchanged even for a wide variety of parameters (DRY). Until MERGE (and except in cases where, say, the app might not know if this item is new or existing), for DML I generally agree with you.

Comment: You'll be scanning when you're trying to update if it doesn't exist.  The question is really, do you want to have good SQL performance or less procs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What version of SQL Server? This information is always useful so please get in the habit of tagging your question with the specific version.

If [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) or greater, you might consider [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of separate `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations, though since writing this answer I have definitely changed my tune and prefer the `UPDATE / IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 / INSERT` methodology you proposed. For more info, see:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

Here is a `MERGE` sample (run it in tempdb), but again I recommend against it in general.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataType
(
    ID             int IDENTITY(1,1),
    TypeName       nvarchar(255),
    [TypeProperty] nvarchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_DataType PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT dbo.DataType(TypeName, [TypeProperty]) VALUES (N'name 1', N'property 1');
GO
```

Then a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MergeDataType
    @ID           int = NULL,
    @TypeName     nvarchar(255),
    @TypeProperty nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH [source](ID, TypeName, [TypeProperty]) AS 
    (
        SELECT @ID, @TypeName, @TypeProperty
    )
    MERGE dbo.DataType WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS [target] 
      USING [source] ON [target].ID = [source].ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET [target].TypeName       = @TypeName,
                   [target].[TypeProperty] = @TypeProperty
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TypeName, [TypeProperty]) 
        VALUES (@TypeName, @TypeProperty);
END
GO
```

Now let's run it and check the results:

```
EXEC dbo.MergeDataType 
    @TypeName     = N'foo', 
    @TypeProperty = N'bar';

EXEC dbo.MergeDataType 
    @ID           = 1, 
    @TypeName     = N'name 1', 
    @TypeProperty = N'new property';
GO

SELECT ID, TypeName, [TypeProperty] FROM dbo.DataType;
GO
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.DataType;
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.MergeDataType;
```

Comment: Sorry re-tagged. It is 08, I was unaware of the MERGE function. I will give that a shot. Thank You

Comment: If MERGE doesn't work out for you for whatever reason, then I'd advocate the separate procedure path - especially if the app knows up front whether this is add or edit, and especially if the stored procedure(s) may get more complex later (and therefore will benefit from separate compiled plans).

Comment: So far everything I am finding on the MERGE function is referencing merging data (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) between two tables. In my case it's going to be a direct call to a single table. Basically I want INSERT/UPDATE based on whether it exists or not. Could you provide an example of this using MERGE or should I just stick to the separate procedures?

Comment: "two tables" don't necessarily need to be actual physical tables. They just need to smell like it.

Comment: Editing your question to see how you do those funky tags

Answer (score -1):

```
USE [//Your Database Name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIcone] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
@amount decimal(18,0),
@payer  nvarchar(50),
@paymentMode  nvarchar(50),
@date date,
@description nvarchar(Max),
@operatorId int
)
AS
begin
if exists (select *  from wallet2 as t where payer=@payer)
begin
    update wallet2 set amount=@amount,payer=@payer,paymentMode=@paymentMode,
    [date]=@date,[description]=@description where id=(select id  from 
    wallet2 as t where payer=@payer) and operatorId=@operatorId
end
else 
begin
         insert into dbo.Wallet2 
         values(@amount,@payer,@paymentMode,@date,@description,@operatorId);
    end

END
```

Comment: Should this be an answer to the question above? At least you should explain your code (and pls. format it as well)